# PCL filter order

Tags: ros, filter, ros-melodic, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using two filters on my pointcloud: CropBox to restrict points to a region and VoxelGrid to downsample the point cloud. Is it faster to run these in some particular order?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339460/pcl-filter-order/) by [mdeegan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50015/mdeegan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In almost all cases, it will be faster to run CropBox first, because it is very fast and can potentially eliminate a lot of points. How large the advantage is depends on your data: If you have a huge point cloud and a small target volume, so that CropBox removes 90% of points, the advantage will be greater than if CropBox only removes 10% of points.

That being said, VoxelGrid is quite fast too, so I suspect in most cases it wouldn't hurt too much to run VoxelGrid first (but there should almost never be an advantage to this).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2019-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2